# Updating iOS 14 Home Widget from StaticConfiguration to IntentConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, sirishortcuts, widgetkit

Has anyone successfully migrated their **iOS 14 Home Widget** from using `StaticConfiguration` to `IntentConfiguration`?

My widgets are completely broken, stuck in placeholder state, after migration. The only solution is to remove and re-add them. This prevents me to ship an update because it would break widgets for all my existing users.

I'm using **iOS 14.0 and Xcode 12.0 (12A7208)**.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did that today, could you please share your code so I can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets start working after iPhone restart.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, but it's not realistic to demand that from users. 